# Создание сайта с множеством видео файлов

Tags: хостинг, видео, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть еще один вопрос! Вот я к примеру хочу сделать сайт на котором любой человек сможет посмотреть какой то сериал или фильм с возможностью скачать его. Возникает вопрос, как это делается? Сверстать сайт это не проблема, а вот куда разместить видео файлы? Если какой нибудь сериал на несколько сезонов весит с пару десятков гигабайт то как мне кажется это проблема!

Я не очень разбираюсь в работе хостингами и прочем, может разжуете мне как это делается?

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать купить выделенный сервер. Либо же, размещать медиа-файлы где-нибудь на файловом хостинге. Яндекс файлы, Народ, Амазон.

Comment: С яндекс диском не работает. Залил туда видео, вырезал код плеера со страницы поставил себе на сайт. Несколько часов работало потом перестало.